# how can place multiple arrays in uipickerview components and when selected row in one component how can get the array in another component

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have one main array (a[8]) in this array have divide 8 sub array and each sub array have
list of elements.so i am using uipickerview and now i am take 3 buttons .when one button 
clicked get single component uipickerview in this picker i did pass main array  into 
pickerview. remaining two button clicked get the two component of uipickerveiw lick as 
taken code given bellow.

```
 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
  {
   if (Picker.tag==1) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return 2;
  }
```

so,My problem is when button one clicked then we selected one row after i clicked 2nd
 button here which  row selected that is passed row in first component placed then 
automatically related array placed into second component . how i can pass the arrays in 
selected row into second component. plz help me.

Answer (score 1):

To get the values loaded into the another component when you click one of the components you can use

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
      if(component == 0)
      {
            //Logic to fetch value from existing component and create a new array for next component
            [pickerView reloadComponent:1];

      }
}
```